# How do I create 5 new rows of randomized data in an ndarray, using the statistical bounds of individual features from an existing DataFrame?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

For my class we have to create 5 new rows of randomized data in an ndarray, using the statistical bounds of each of the individual features in an existing DataFrame

[The DataFrame in question:] https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8rMK.png

[And the expected output(with different values):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvT30.png)

According to the assessment we are expected to use a for loop but I'm at a complete loss right now. I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)